# Binding Silverlight Charts in Code Behind

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a list of objects (custom) with two properties each (date, value) and I'd like to bind this list to a LineSeries object.

This is what I have so far...

```
        var series = new LineSeries();
        series.ItemsSource = this._storObj;  // This is the List<object>
        storageChart.Series.Add(series);
```

How do I tell the series what properties to use on the objects in the code-behind. I've seen many XAML examples but need to do this in the code behind.

Thanks!

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```
series.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("NameOfYourValueProperty");
series.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Date");
```

Hope that helps ;)